# DEPTH of javascript recursive function

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to save a json structure in mongodb, but I'd like to get the depth of recursiveness (`DEPTH`) that each item has when looping through this function. How can I achieve this reusing the following function?:

```
_.mixin({
    importJsonItemsToMongo: function (obj, opt, iterator) {
        function recurse (json_item) {
            // console.log(`level ${DEPTH}: ${json_item.name}`);
            db.collection('json_import_items').insert(json_item);
            _.each(json_item.child_items, _.importJsonItemsToMongo);
        };
        recurse(obj);
    }
});
_.each(jsonResponse.child_items, _.importJsonItemsToMongo);
```

Comment: where is `DEPTH` in the code?

Comment: Yes, just DEPTH is missing!

Comment: There isn't. That is exactly what I want to find

Comment: @Keith's answer is Perfect

Comment: @Keith's seems good, but it was deleted. It's not working correctly, I get everything level 1. Maybe he will post something soon. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how underscore.js does work, but I guess, it can be done like this:

```
_.mixin({
    importJsonItemsToMongo: function (obj, depth) {
        console.log(`level ${DEPTH}: ${obj.name}`);

        db.collection('json_import_items').insert(obj);

        _.each(obj.child_items, function(x) {
            _.importJsonItemsToMongo(x, depth + 1);
        });
    }
});
_.each(jsonResponse.child_items, function(x) {
    _.importJsonItemsToMongo(x, 0);
});
```

I have just added a depth argument; and have removed unused arguments, you can add it back, if you need.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt with a closure for the depth.

```
_.mixin({
    importJsonItemsToMongo: function(DEPTH) {
        return function (obj, opt, iterator) {
            function recurse (json_item) {
                // console.log(`level ${DEPTH}: ${json_item.name}`);
                db.collection('json_import_items').insert(json_item);
                _.each(json_item.child_items, _.importJsonItemsToMongo(DEPTH + 1));
            };
            recurse(obj);
        };
    }
});
_.each(jsonResponse.child_items, _.importJsonItemsToMongo(0));
```